# ternary conditional operator If Else C#

Tags: c#, winforms

i wrote this code:

```
        if (B_21_GDV_Variant.RowCount > 0)
        {
            metroContextMenuStrip1.Enabled = true;
            B_21_GDV_Variant.AllowDeleting = false;
            B_21_GDV_Variant.Columns["HB"].Format = "{0:N}";
            B_21_GDV_Variant.Columns["HB"].CellStyle.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        }
        else
        {
            metroContextMenuStrip1.Enabled = false;
            B_21_GDV_Variant.AllowDeleting = true;
        }
```

I just want to know, how to write it using ternary conditional operator ?

Comment: No, this code is awful if you try to turn it into a ternary operator. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest form would be this:

```
_ = (B_21_GDV_Variant.RowCount > 0)
    ? new Func<bool>(() => 
    {
        metroContextMenuStrip1.Enabled = true;
        B_21_GDV_Variant.AllowDeleting = false;
        B_21_GDV_Variant.Columns["HB"].Format = "{0:N}";
        B_21_GDV_Variant.Columns["HB"].CellStyle.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        return true;
    })()
    : new Func<bool>(() => 
    {
        metroContextMenuStrip1.Enabled = false;
        B_21_GDV_Variant.AllowDeleting = true;
        return false;
    })();
```

That is, the ternary operator must return a value, which is here discarded (see the underscore).

The solution to wrap more operations is to enclose them in a delegate (Func in this case), then immediately executed (see the parens pair at the very end of each block).

Technically feasible, but I honestly don't see any convenience in doing that.

Comment: this is a complete answer, concluding that, using a ternary for simple operations like my question might result in somewhat hard to read code.

thanks for the answer, I can learn a lot from here.

Comment: This is using side-effects to mutate variables with a completely nonsense `bool` as a return into what appears to be an anonymous variable. It's quite awful.

Comment: @Enigmativity interesting to discuss, what is the meaning of something terrible?

Comment: @Philipe - I'm happy to discuss. Can you clarify what you're asking as I didn't use the word "terrible"?

Comment: @Enigmativity I mean when you say "It's quite awful".. what actually happens to the code that "Mario" wrote when it was implemented ?

Comment: @Enigmativity I completely agree with you: I would never use such a form. However, since the Philipe question has (at least to me) educational purpose, I just shown a way to write. By the way, in JavaScript is a very common solution, even without returning a value.

Comment: @Philipe - It's just overly complicated code that could be written more simply in the way you posted in your question.

Comment: @MarioVernari when I said (just curious), your answer has become input for me to study, and will not be used.. thanks again for the explanation Mario..

Comment: @Enigmativity your input is also very useful for me, thank you for that, and nice to meet you Enigmativity :)

Answer (score 3):

In general, it may not be recommended in this context, but it's still possible. Not only ternary conditional operator, but also using direct boolean values to set. This is:

```cs
metroContextMenuStrip1.Enabled = (B_21_GDV_Variant.RowCount > 0);
B_21_GDV_Variant.AllowDeleting = !(B_21_GDV_Variant.RowCount > 0);
B_21_GDV_Variant.Columns["HB"].Format = (B_21_GDV_Variant.RowCount > 0) ? "{0:N}" : B_21_GDV_Variant.Columns["HB"].Format;
B_21_GDV_Variant.Columns["HB"].CellStyle.HorizontalAlignment = (B_21_GDV_Variant.RowCount > 0) ? HorizontalAlignment.Left : B_21_GDV_Variant.Columns["HB"].CellStyle.HorizontalAlignment;
```

I would not recommend using the ternary conditional operator in this case since it does not help with readability and in general using it in this case will not generate any performance improvement.

Comment: ah.. turns out this can be implemented, meaning maybe the code results will be hard to read and unfriendly.. but this has answered my curiosity to learn.. thank you very much..

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to force the use of ternary and you wanted some semblance of readability, then I'd suggest this:

```
var data = 
    B_21_GDV_Variant.RowCount > 0
    ? (
        Enabled: true,
        AllowDeleting: false,
        Format: "{0:N}",
        HorizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Left
    )
    : (
        Enabled: false,
        AllowDeleting: true,
        Format: B_21_GDV_Variant.Columns["HB"].Format,
        HorizontalAlignment: B_21_GDV_Variant.Columns["HB"].CellStyle.HorizontalAlignment
    );

metroContextMenuStrip1.Enabled = data.Enabled;
B_21_GDV_Variant.AllowDeleting = data.AllowDeleting;
B_21_GDV_Variant.Columns["HB"].Format = data.Format;
B_21_GDV_Variant.Columns["HB"].CellStyle.HorizontalAlignment = data.HorizontalAlignment;
```

Comment: As readibility, not better than mine, IMHO. Moreover, it works only until you've something to return. Can't call `void`'s. To me, the Philipe original form is the best one: by far and away.

Comment: @MarioVernari - I fear you're biased. What has calling `void` got to do with it? Yours doesn't. The OP's doesn't. And mine doesn't.

Comment: we're talking about "the nothing". However, here is what I mean: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hF2tlr . Why my solution? because in JavaScript this form is very common, instead: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-ternary-operator/ . That being said, I would never ever use it, both in C# and in JS. Mate, nothing against you or your solution: BTW, I didn't downvote your answer.